# MOSFET Saturation Voltage vs. Gate Voltage

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Currently, I'm evaluating data from a lab course about MOSFETs. I read that the saturation voltage is given by
$$V_\text{D,sat}=V_\text{G}-V_\text{th}.$$
It turns out that my data shows some kind of quadratic dependency
$$V_\text{D,sat}\sim(V_\text{G}-V_\text{th})^2$$
which I don't really understand.

Is there an effect I'm not aware of responsible for this? I simulated the measurement circuit with LTSPICE and also got the linear dependency, which is why I'm confused.
[image][image]

Comment: Which MOSFET are you using? Maybe the datasheet can tell us more about its behavior.

Comment: It's a BS 170 MOSFET

Comment: What's the range of Vds and Vgs you're using? (Sorry for not adding this to my earlier question). What drain currents do you get?

Comment: I just put in the plots I have. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Looking at those plots, I'd estimate the saturation voltage to be closer to 0.7V in the Vgs=3.3V case, rather than almost 0.9V. What's the definition you use to determine the saturation voltage?

Comment: As a definition I used a relative 1/e^2 decay from the maximum of the differential current. But I don't think that doing it differently would change the overall quadratic behavoir.

Comment: There is no built-in BS170 model within LTspice, so you must've gotten it elsewhere.  If the subcircuit is built around a Level 1 or 2 MOSFET model, it needs `LAMBDA` defined.  If it uses a Level 3 then it needs `KAPPA` defined.  What happens if you use the 2N7002 model that is built into LTspice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going to bite you with your current way of determining the saturation voltage is the channel-length modulation (MOSFET equivalent of a BJT's Early effect). It adds an offset to the differential current. Your Spice simulation doesn't take this effect into account.

You can try to eliminate its influence by subtracting the asymptotic value from the differential current first. The simplest way would be to subtract the value at Vds=3.5V from all the differential current curves so that the new curves are zero at Vds=3.5V. (This is valid since at that point, the MOSFET is in saturation and only the channel length modulation influences its Id/Vds curve.)

Once you've taken care of the channel length modulation, the next problem is that real devices don't abruptly go into saturation; instead, they taper off as they near saturation. You can work around this problem by adding a tangent to your differential current graph at its steepest point (though you might want to smooth out the curve slightly beforehand so that small measurement errors don't influence the result so much). The point at which the tangent intersects the X axis is the saturation voltage.

This method is mathematically accurate since the MOSFET's Id/Vds curve is quadratic in the ohmic region, and the first derivative of Id/Vds is therefore linear, which means that it is equal to its tangent in an ideal world. However, extrapolating from lower Vds avoids the partial-saturation effects that you get at higher Vds, which would otherwise skew the result. (The differential current graph diverges from the theoretical ideal at higher Vds, which is quite easy to see when you compare the graphs you have with the ones that Spice gave you.)

There's also an easy physical explanation for why this MOSFET diverges from the ideal behavior so much around the saturation point: The BS170 isn't actually a single MOSFET, it's constructed from many tiny MOSFETs in parallel, and they don't all have the exact same characteristics. To measure its saturation voltage accurately, you have to extrapolate from a lower Vds (using the fact that the Vds/Ids relationship is quadratic in the ohmic region), because the MOSFET's behavior around the saturation point is just too much of a mess to get accurate results.